# How do I get rid of the node title on a specific view mode?

Tags: 7, display-suite, entities

I'm using Drupal 7 with *Omega subtheme* and [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) module.

I have a content type and the nodes are displayed as default (Full Content). But I have two or three nodes of this content type which must be displayed in slightly different way (just a few fields hidden, some others perhaps).

So using [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) I've created a new *view mode* for these specific nodes and on the *content edit* page I've selected new *view mode* rather than *Default*.

Now the problem with this new mode is that node's title is rendered twice, once as the *page title* and second as the *node title*. This is different from the *Default/Full Content* mode, which seems to just have a *page title* and no node title.

How to get a rid of the *node title* on the new view mode so it's the same as the way *Default/Full Content* displays are shown (without using Views)?

Maybe there's some way to clone the *Full Content* view mode and then just edit that clone. So the new *view mode* also only shows a *page title* not the node title?

Comment: Answer on this question may help you http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/107895/hide-title-for-rendered-entity-views/169664#169664

Answer (score 11):

Since already using Display Suite you can enable Extras module in orde to hide page title

DS config
admin/structure/ds/extras

Tab "Other"
Check "Page title options"

Node Manage Display
admin/structure/types/manage/article/display/full

Tab "Layout for article full"
select Hide "Page title"

Comment: You'll need to ensure you're using the "Full content" view mode for this to work (you may not be by default).

Comment: a vote up for display suite.

Answer (score 2):

sounds to me like a theming error. you probably have forgotten to check in the `node.tpl.php` if the node is being viewed or not.
regularly there is no title set

```
<?php if (!$page): ?>
  <h2<?php print $title_attributes; ?>>
    <a href="<?php print $node_url; ?>"><?php print $title; ?></a>
  </h2>
<?php endif; ?>
```

you can check for the $view_mode in the node template file and depending on that, set the titel (or dont set it). dont forget, that on the full view_mode, the page variable is set to true.

Answer (score 1):

If anybody wants to solve this problem programmatically from template.php or a custom module:

```
/**
 * Implements template/hook_preprocess_node().
 */
function MYTEMPLATE/MYMODULE_preprocess_node(&$vars) {

  if ($vars['view_mode'] != 'full') {

    $vars['title'] = FALSE; // hides second title
  }
}
```